# Sampling non-repeating integers with given probability distribution

Tags: numpy, random, sampling, probability-distribution

I need to sample *n* different values taken from a set of integers.

These integers should have different occurence probability. E.g. the largest the lukilier.

By using the `random` package I can sample a set of different values from the set, by maeans of the method

```
random.sample
```

However it doesn't seem to provide the possibility to associate a probability distribution.

On the other hand there is the `numpy` package which allows to associate the distribution, but it returns a sample with repetitions. This can be done with the method

```
numpy.random.choice
```

I am looking for a method (or a way around) to do what the two methods do, but together.

Comment: `numpy.random.choice([1, 2, 3], size=n, p=[0.1, 0.3, 0.6])`?

Comment: suppose n=3, then I want the output to be [1,2,3], but I may get [3,3,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use `numpy.random.choice` as it has the `replace` parameter. If set to `False`, the sampling will be done wihtout remplacement.

Here's a random example:

```
>>> np.random.choice([1, 2, 4, 6, 9], 3, replace=False, p=[1/2, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8])
>>> array([1, 9, 4])
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. This actually answers the question I posted, while mine answers what I really meant.